# One war calling another in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I am currently implementing a small application A. This application A gets some objects from users and will do some preprocessing, before it passes these objects into a different web application B, which finally will store information of these objects.

Now to the question: What are possible approaches to call application B from application A? And which one is the most efficient (in terms of run-time speed)?

This call is one-way, possibly can be done asynchronous and always will happen in the same tomcat server.

Comment: you can use a `webservice` to do that, `B` calls a service provided by `A`

Comment: Plenty of possibilities from message queues to direct connections through different protocols (such as REST/HTTP). You shouldn't worry about efficiency just yet though.

Comment: @RafikBELDI: Thank you for your input, what kind of webservice are you talking about? And which type would you recommend for runtime efficiency?

Comment: @Kayaman Why shouldn't I worry about efficiency yet? It is a hard requirement that we keep the each call below 10ms and quite some heavy calculations have to be done during that time, so efficiency is actually my main concern..

Comment: @kajk Well because you don't seem to have any idea what you're doing since you're asking this question. Your main concern should be learning to communicate in *any* way between your web applications, not wondering about the theoretical speed of the solution you don't have. But at least now you have a keyword you can google (webservices), you're still miles from a solution though.

Comment: @Kayaman: Why are you assuming I don't have *any* idea what I'm talking about?? I feels like you are trying to insult me.
I know of a couple of possible approaches of how these services could communicate, but I also added the additional stipulation of efficiency because it is important.
I know of REST and we are using that in other areas of the application, I know of SOAP which we are also using for a different use case, I know of sockets which I also have used. But I don't know what is a good and **efficient** approach to communication between two applications in the *same* tomcat container.

Comment: @kajk Because nothing in your question indicates that you know what you're talking about. You're asking for a list as if we were your free personal consultants. Why didn't you mention that you're already using SOAP elsewhere? Besides, why didn't you go to Google instead of coming here and dumping your problem and getting insulted that you're not provided a gift wrapped solution?

Comment: @Kayaman: Sorry I didn't mention different ideas I already thought of in the question, but thought it would be counter productive to provide different possible solutions in the question. I can add them later if you think that makes sense? I was googling during the last couple of hours before I came to SO, exactly because I don't think anybody here is a free-of-charge consultant. But I don't know Tomcat that good so my searches weren't as fruitful as I hoped, which is why I am here. Hoping somebody has can point me in a good direction or even give some sort of solution.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to change it in terms of architecture: Monolith vs Microservice.

You can expose REST, WSDL (soap) services in both applications to the others also externally.

In generall REST is less standardized than SOAP, also WSDL requires such contract installment

REST is protocol independent, can use any protocol for which there is an standardized URI scheme

Comment: I sadly don't have enough time to rewrite the whole application *B* to modularise it into multiple microservices.. But that is anyway out of the scope of this question..
Doesn't a rest- or soap-api have a rather big overhead? Aren't there other approaches to communicate between applications in the same tomcat server with less overhead?

Answer (score 1):

Use an in-memory message queue such as [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) which provides fast asyncronous communication, constantly open connections (avoiding connect delays that REST would have) and plenty of other things.

Comment: Sorry I haven't used SO in a while, because my own research usually was enough. I didn't see that option for "asking for recommendations". Thank you very much for the MQ pointer, it seems like a very good option here.

Comment: No worries, it's just frustrating from an answerer's point of view when the questions are not informative enough.